How to make Worker class compatible with AutoFac also with Microsoft Dependency Injections
I have an worker service what will be consumed in two project.
First project use Autofac for dependency injection the other use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
First Worker look like:
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
...
    public Worker(

        [KeyFilter(ChannelKeys.Name1)] 
        Channel<Dictionary<string, object>> dataChannel1,        
        [KeyFilter(ChannelKeys.Name2)] 
        Channel<Dictionary<string, object>> dataChannel2,
        ...
 )

}

the other same but other attributes:
    public Worker(

        [FromKeyedServices(ChannelKeys.Name1)]
        Channel<Dictionary<string, object>> dataChannel1,        
        [FromKeyedServices(ChannelKeys.Name2)]
        Channel<Dictionary<string, object>> dataChannel2,
        ...

how to unify that i have only one worker to maintain?

Some libraries ship separate DI-packages for specific DI Frameworks. Like there is "Library" and then "Library.MicrosoftDI" and "Library.Autofac" - that's one step. The other would be to withdraw anything from the "common" code that is specific to one of those DI-Frameworks. Either you find a common abstraction both support or you need to find a way to move the bifurcation to a point where you need to be DI-Framework specific anyway.

By now most libraries use the .NET DI abstractions. You can use the .NET DI abstractions while using a different IoC library. You can use .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory()) to replace the .NET DI provider with Autofac.

^^ Which would be the "common abstraction both support". Didn't know you could do that with autofac. Maybe my employer is too locked-in to MS ...

I think the functionality was always there, and all IoC libraries that are still around offer a way to integrate. It's hard for a library to survive without supporting ASP.NET Core for the last 7 years
